# When does postgresql need to write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp"?

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-10

Postgres (version 10.10) crashed on my machine (database connection became impossible). I checked the logs and saw

```
2019-10-11 15:46:41.262 UTC [30233] postgres_prod@syntax_prod LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2019-10-11 17:41:06.104 UTC [2001] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
2019-10-11 17:41:06.364 UTC [1999] LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 2001) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2019-10-11 17:41:06.364 UTC [1999] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-10-11 17:41:06.364 UTC [1326] postgres_prod@syntax_prod WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-10-11 17:41:06.364 UTC [1326] postgres_prod@syntax_prod DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
...
```

I assume the problem occurred with

```
PANIC: could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
```

But I have 77 gigabytes left on my machine (I just restarted Postgres and so far everything works fine). So I don't really understand the PANIC error message. I figured that knowing more about postgres having to write to the file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp" may help me to understand what went wrong. So I'm looking for information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have 77 gigabytes left on my machine

Presumably you didn't at the time the error occurred, or the available space is on the wrong partition to be used.  There may have been a lot of temp files which got cleaned up after the error, so free space now doesn't mean you had free space then.  Maybe you could set up a temp tablespace on a different partition, where it wouldn't be able to run other things out of space and crash the whole system?

> I figured that knowing more about postgres having to write to the file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp" may help me to understand what went wrong.

I'm pretty sure that it won't.  But this is part of checkpointing the progress of logical replication.  It creates a new file, then atomically renames it over the old one.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat disappointing, but I guess it makes a lot of sense. I have no idea what would cause my disk to run out of space so quickly and then coming back to normal again...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. This command seems to resolve my issue:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker martin/docker-cleanup-volumes
```